# list comprehension example for variable inner list

Tags: python, list, compression

I am working on list comprehension in python.

```
l = [['200801', '100'], ['', ''], ['200802', '151'], [''], ['200805', '160'] ,['', u''], [''], [u'\xa0'], ['\r\n                       \r\n                        ', '\r\n                      '], ['200812', '50']]
```

I want output as

```
[['200801', '100'], ['200802', '151'], ['200805', '160'], ['200812', '50']]
```

How can I remove such uncertain inner list of variable length and extra characters?

Comment: You need to define _"What is to be removed?"_ and _"What is to be kept?"_. Otherwise we are all wasting time guessing what you are thinking

Comment: Also, when you say "I am working on list comprehension", you should help us by showing your list comprehension... there is none in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
>>> [x for x in l if all(y.strip() for y in x)]
[['200801', '100'], ['200802', '151'], ['200805', '160'], ['200812', '50']]
```

I don't like it much though, it's doing too much in one line.

If you could describe better what you are trying to *words*, you'll find it a lot easier to describe in *Python* (or any other language).

Comment: Could also be `y.isdigit()` depending on the intent of the OP

Comment: @gnibbler: Could be. The specification was sorely lacking.

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expressions to search for patterns that look like numbers.

```py
>>> x = [['200801', '100'], ['', ''], ['200802', '151'], [''], ['200805', '160'] ,['', u''], [''], [u'\xa0'], ['\r\n                       \r\n                        ', '\r\n                      '], ['200812', '50']]
>>> import re
>>> [p for p in x if all(re.match(r'\d+', q) for q in p)]
[['200801', '100'], ['200802', '151'], ['200805', '160'], ['200812', '50']]
```

Answer (score 4):

`join` can come in handy here

```
# keep only non-empty lists
print [x for x in l if ''.join(x).strip()]

# keep only lists with digits
print [x for x in l if ''.join(x).isdigit()]
```